# Changing text everytime hit the button?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make this system which is every time you click a button you will **continue in order** not in random sequence

```js
const stn = [`Hi`, `Hey`, `Hello`]
            //  0         1       2

function buttOn() {
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = stn[0]
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = stn[1]
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = stn[2]
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="txt"></p>
    <br>
    <button id="buttOn" onclick="buttOn()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

**This is what I got but I can't seems to make it stop at stn[0] and it's just go to the last which is stn[2]**

Comment: you need to store the index as a counter variable then increment it each button press.

Comment: Use `Math.random` to choose a random index.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that? Running three of these calls directly behind one another will obviously not do what you expect

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to give the idea of it

Answer (score 0):

Create an index variable, and increment its value when button is clicked each time, inside the `buttOn()` function.

```js
const stn = [`Hi`, `Hey`, `Hello`]
            //  0         1       2
            
let index = 0;

function buttOn() {
    let text = stn[index];
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = text;
    index += 1;
    
    if(index > stn.length -1) index = 0;       //Reset the index back to 0 when it exceeds the index count of array
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="txt"></p>
    <br>
    <button id="buttOn" onclick="buttOn()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your button method like this

```js
let index = 0;

function buttOn() {
    // reset the index if we have reached to the end of the list
    if (index >= stn.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    // use index value to update the txt
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = stn[index];
    // increment the index so that next time this function is called,
    // an updated value of index is used
    index++;
}

// you can also use a closure function to avoid a global variable

const buttOn = (function() {
    stn = [`Hi`, `Hey`, `Hello`];
    let index = 0;
    return () => {
       // reset the index if we have reached to the end of the list
       if (index >= stn.length) {
           index = 0;
       }
       // use index value to update the txt
       document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = stn[index];
       // increment the index so that next time this function is called,
       // an updated value of index is used
       index++;
    };

})();
```

References

1. [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to increment each time after the button click and after that get the current index as

```
index = index % stn.length;
```

```js
const stn = [`Hi`, `Hey`, `Hello`]
//  0         1       2
let index = 0;

function buttOn() {
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = stn[index++];
  index = index % stn.length;
}
```

```html
<p id="txt"></p>
<br>
<button id="buttOn" onclick="buttOn()">Click Me!</button>
```